# Apache POI : Issue during setting foreground color in conditionalFormatting with SOLID_FILL pattern

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-poi

I want to apply a formatting to achieve row striped format(odd row : grey and even row : no background color) in generated excel sheet using Apache POI.

Following is related code :

```
       val sheetCF = sheet.sheetConditionalFormatting       
       val rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(
        "MOD(ROW(), 2) = 0")

       val fill1 = rule1.createPatternFormatting()
       fill1.setFillForegroundColor( XSSFColor(Color(245,245,245),DefaultIndexedColorMap())) // Light Gray color
      fill1.fillPattern = PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND // this is causing issue
      val regions1 = arrayOf(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:D10"))   
      sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions1, rule1)
```

Due to fillPattern, white color is applied as foreground. But if any other fillPattern is used , then it's working. Example:
           `fill1.fillPattern = PatternFormatting.BIG_SPOTS`

But I need to apply solid patter. 
Any help would be appreciate in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to how you usually color the cell, with `XSSFConditionalFormattingRule` you actually have to use `setFillBackgroundColor()` instead of `setFillForegroundColor()`.

```
XSSFConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting().createConditionalFormattingRule("MOD(ROW(), 2) = 0");
XSSFPatternFormatting fill = rule.createPatternFormatting();
fill.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
fill.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND.getCode());
CellRangeAddress[] regions = { CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A2:Z" + (sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1)) };

sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting().addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule);
```

Comment: If I will use setFillBackgroundColor, then I won't be able to change any cell's color manually after opening excel sheet.
@XtremeBaumer

Comment: That is because the rule specifies the color. You can only change the color for the whole rule, which would affect every row. You have the same behaviour if you create a conditional formatting manually in excel

Comment: In that case, I cannot use Conditional formatting. Style need to be applied to each cell to achieve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `PatternFormatting` the solid background fill really needs to be set using `PatternFormatting.setFillBackgroundColor` also for a solid pattern fill. This is different from `CellStyle` where the fill foreground color needs to be set for solid pattern fill. The fill foreground color is the color of the pattern and the fill background color is the color behind the pattern.

Let's have a complete example to show this and which is able serving both `XSSF`as well as `HSSF`.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class CreateExcelConditionalFormatting {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelConditionalFormatting.xls";
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelConditionalFormatting.xlsx";

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

  ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("MOD(ROW(), 2) = 0");
  PatternFormatting fill = rule.createPatternFormatting();
  if (fill instanceof XSSFPatternFormatting) {
   fill.setFillBackgroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(245,245,245),new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
  } else if (fill instanceof HSSFPatternFormatting){
   HSSFPalette palette = ((HSSFWorkbook)workbook).getCustomPalette();
   HSSFColor hssfColor = palette.findColor((byte)245, (byte)245, (byte)245); 
   if (hssfColor == null) {
    palette.setColorAtIndex((short)63, (byte)245, (byte)245, (byte)245);
    hssfColor = palette.getColor((short)63);
   }
   fill.setFillBackgroundColor(hssfColor);
  }
  fill.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

  ConditionalFormattingRule[] cfRules = new ConditionalFormattingRule[]{rule};

  CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:D10")};

  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cfRules);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```